# How to put a sidewalk on a slanted hill?

Tags: leveling, sidewalk

If I had to guess I would say grade along my house is about 30%. I am just wondering if there is another way besides leveling off the part for the walkway.

Comment: Definitely add a picture - worth 1,000 words. 30% sounds VERY steep - more like stairs, with a railing, than a simple sidewalk.

Comment: You are most likely overestimating the grade. 2-3% is the top a train can take. 5% is a climb you feel clearly when walking/biking. More than 10% is a good exercise. 30% is something you find on a ski slope or skateboard park. Please measure. 
I'd make a joke about 30% being good for your sanity as they won't stay long, but that would be inappropriate.

Comment: what exactly is a *slanted hill* ?

Comment: Don't forget that max slope for manual wheelchairs is 8% and powered chairs is 12%.

Comment: If the contractor suggested **leveling** the slope, it is likely that the slope is going downhill from the house, while the person is trying to walk across the slope, not up or down it. It wouldn't make sense to level a slope to build stairs.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re working in the “Right-of-Way” you’d better contact the City and verify compliance with their Standards for Construction”.

The notion that the sidewalk needs to comply with ADA is nonsense, if you’re located on a 30 degree slope. First, ADA is for public “use” building sites, and second it’s not required for extreme sloped sites that create a hardship.

However, the City will have many requirements and you’ll need a permit to work in the right-of-way, including how and when you can block off the roadway to perform the work.

Answer (score 0):

Many sidewalks in San Francisco have a significant slope, thus your ability to pour concrete on a slope isn't an issue. Thus, you should consider:

- (as Jim Stewart mentions below) the capabilities of your in laws to traverse such a steep slope, especially if they may be in a wheelchair in the future
- checking with your city's building department about what is allowed.

For instance, the ADA requirements for a wheel chair ramp is a 1:12 slope  (rise of 1 foot over a 12 foot distance or in other words 1 inch per foot). However, [in this thread](http://www.diychatroom.com/f19/concrete-forms-sloping-sidewalk-44641/) one contractor says that he had trouble getting approval for a 1:10 slope walkway.

Comment: Look up specifications for wheelchair ramps. You may be be surprised at the limits on what is allowed, but if you ignore these specifications it may cost you a bundle in insurance premiums, and the city might may you redo a ramp which doesn't comply.

Comment: The reason I referred to wheelchair ramps is that the addition is for "inlaws" which I assumed meant his wife's parents. They may be or may become mobility impaired.

Answer (score 0):

If I read you right, you're talking about a sidewalk parallel to the slope, not uphill / downhill.

There's really no alternative to leveling the path.  A small crown or pitch left to right is fine for a sidewalk, but anything more is really awkward and hard on the ankles, possibly hazardous when slippery.

In some cases, a deck walkway may work out better for you than a sidewalk, just something to consider.